Confidence intervals in beta regressions
I am using a mixed-effects beta regression model in my study because my values are bounded between 0 and 1. When I run the same analysis using a linear mixed-effects model, I obtain similar results (predictors have the same directions and are significant). In the linear model, the confidence intervals remain within the bounds of the data (i.e., no negative values or values greater than 1), making them straightforward to interpret. Although the effects are significant, the confidence intervals suggest a small effect size, which I would like to report.
However, from what I’ve read, beta regression is more appropriate for my data. I can report the confidence intervals from the beta regression model, but is there a way to transform them to make interpretation easier? Additionally, is there a metric in beta regression that is similar to an effect size?

By confidence intervals do you mean the confidence intervals on the parameters, or on the predictions? For maximum interpretability I would look at marginal effects, e.g. via the marginaleffects package in R ...

The confidence intervals for the parameters. Thanks for suggesting marginaleffects. From what I understand, avg_slopes(model) provides the confidence intervals on the original scale of the response, correct?

@ArthurFaraco Average slopes provides confidence intervals for the average derivative of the conditional expectation function with respect to the parameter.

@DemetriPananos thanks!

Beta regression models typically use a logit link, which means that the effects (parameter magnitudes or CIs) can't easily be translated to the probability scale without picking a baseline value (unlike identity-link models or log-link models such as Poisson regression). That's why epidemiologists spend so much time learning about how the logit link works (e.g. Breen et al 2018, ref below).  You can report the coefficients and their CIs, or you can report the scaled coefficients (Schielzeth 2010), which at least makes the coefficients unitless. For interpretation, see also here, or section 5.2 of Gelman and Hill Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models. It may be simplest to compute marginal effects, as in the marginaleffects package: as discussed in the comments, avg_slopes() would give the average derivatives of the conditional expectation function with respect to the parameters, and their confidence intervals; if you want to scale the predictors to get a unitless result (i.e., expected average change in probability per 1-SD change in the predictor), you can use avg_comparisons(model, variables = list("x" = "sd"))
https://x.com/stephenjwild/status/1774434308540760220


Breen, Richard, Kristian Bernt Karlson, and Anders Holm. “Interpreting and Understanding Logits, Probits, and Other Nonlinear Probability Models.” Annual Review of Sociology 44, no. Volume 44, 2018 (July 30, 2018): 39–54. https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-soc-073117-041429.
Schielzeth, Holger. “Simple Means to Improve the Interpretability of Regression Coefficients: Interpretation of Regression Coefficients.” Methods in Ecology and Evolution 1, no. 2 (February 10, 2010): 103–13. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2010.00012.x.

(+1) Insightful commentary, a relevant Stats meme and super-informative references. Xmas came early.

In marginaleffects, the avg_comparisons(model, variables = list("x" = "sd")) command gives you the average change in expected outcome associated to a change of 1 standard deviation about the observed value of x.

Thank you so much!
